# GCC compile error : declaration of ‘strlen’ must be available

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

My problem is that when I want to make a downloaded library I get some weird compile errors from [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) and the code that the compiler demands to correct seems just to be right.

The errors are all like this:

> Catalogue.h:96: error: there are no
>   arguments to ‘strlen’ that depend on a
>   template parameter, so a declaration
>   of ‘strlen’ must be available

Here is the code around line 96:

```
GaCatalogueEntry(const char* name, T* data)
{
    if( name )
    {
        _nameLength = (int)strlen( name ); // LINE 96

        // copy name
        _name = new char[ _nameLength + 1 ];
        strcpy( _name, name );       // LINE 100: similar error

        _data = data;

        return;
    }

    _name = NULL;
    _nameLength = 0;
    _data = NULL;
}
```

What can I do to fix these compile errors?

Comment: It seems you have a set of globals with names that match `_[a-z].*` , those names are reserved for the implementation. (`_[a-z].*` is OK for non-global names such as local variables and class members)

Comment: I don't think they're globals - but rather member variables.  I'm guessing GaCatalogueEntry is a member function in a templated class.  But you're right, it's dangerous to have a naming convention that involves underscore prefixes.  For member variables, it's better to use the m_ prefix, or the _ suffix.

Answer (score 11):

You probably just need to include the header that contains the strcpy and strlen library functions.

```
#include <string.h>
```

or (preferably for C++)

```
#include <cstring>
```

Comment: much better ! (and you have to use std::strlen() instead of just strlen).

Answer (score 4):

In C++ the strlen() function is part of the string library, and it almost looks like the header file was not included.

Is it included anywhere?

```
include <string.h>
```

If not, try adding it and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the missing header file. but I think error messages are not as leading as languages such as java.

Comment: In this case, the cause of the error was obfuscated somewhat by the fact that the code was part of a template. The compiler found an unidentified symbol in the template, which wouldn't even have caused an error until the template was actually instantiated if the unidentified symbol was dependent on the template parameter T, (e.g. if the symbol was something like T::dosomething())

Answer (score 3):

The code is buggy. You are probably missing an `#include <string.h>`.

If you don't want to change the code, add `-fpermissive` to the compiler options. (See the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Name-lookup.html).)

Answer (score 1):

> a declaration of ‘strlen’ must be available

Include `string.h` or `<cstring>` (C++) for the declaration of `strlen()`.